# Are there any reliable and updated sources or feeds for password dumps?

Tags: passwords, account-security, have-i-been-pwned

I am looking for any reliable, up-to-date sources (which may be RSS feeds, websites, or anything else OSINT-based) which contain password dumps and their relative links.

I am looking particularly for the full dumps.

Does anybody know where can I find them?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off-topic and the answers could be never ending.